# How to look for implementations of universal hashing?

Tags: authentication, openssl, universal-hash, carter-wegman, umac

Being a physicist, I know very little about cryptography. In fact, the main two practical aspects I've learned so far are: Unless you're an expert, 1. Don't try to invent new cryptosystems and 2. Don't implement cryptographic algorithms yourself if you can avoid it.

I need an implementation of information-theoretically secure authentication. For this, I intend to use a Carter-Wegman type scheme and thus need an implementation of a $\epsilon\text{-almost strongly universal}_2$ family of hash functions.

Many of the well-known published ways to construct such families seem reasonably straightforward to implement using (perhaps not in the most efficient way possible). However, I'm assuming it's a fundamentally bad idea for a non-expert to start implementing cryptosystems. My question: **How do I find and select an implementation of information-theoretically secure authentication that I can use?**

I'm looking for an open source solution that I can use from C and or C++ and possibly even squeeze into an embedded system as well. The final goal is not a commercial system (i.e. nobody will ever actually try to hack it) but should demonstrate best practices where ever possible.

Are there standards for this? I was assuming OpenSSL or similar well-known libraries must certainly have it but so far the official documentation has not helped me in this respect. How can I find out?

*Disclaimer: If I understand correctly it is a site policy to not recommend concrete implementations of cryptosystems. Although I wouldn't mind such suggestions if the policy allows it, that is not the essence of my question. Rather, I am asking for general principles how a non-expert should approach implementing/finding and using cryptosystems, in the particular case of universal hashing.*

Comment: A fair warning: Information-theoretically secure authentication is very rare as an offered primitive by a library (because the size of the key grows linearly in the number of messages you want to authenticate). However quite a few libraries will offer you MACs based on them and / or modes based on them (e.g. GCM).

Comment: To extend SEJPM's comment, I believe that with a plausible assumption (that where is no value $z$ s.t. $z = AES_k(0)$ holds for a large number of AES keys $k$), GMAC is informationally secure (if you use an independently chosen random key for each message).

Comment: I'll also add that Poly1305 is another MAC based on a WC universal hash. As long as you have a unique key per message, it's information theoretically secure. Of course since Poly1305 only takes a 256-bit key there are "only" 2^256 possible keys, so for an infinite message set the uniqueness requirement is violated. In practice it's just as secure without needing to have an ever-increasing key size. If that's not an issue (for security it isn't, you'll never get a collision if you generate a new key each time) you can use monocypher's crypto_poly1305 functions.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the suggestions. Unfortunately my use-case really requires information theoretic security (e.g. I must assume that adversaries are able to break AES). Does this mean I should implement the system myself from scratch after all? Or should I really use Poly1305 and change the key every round? (I assume this is a wasteful use of key material?)

Comment: You can't get information-theoretic security without the key space being equal in size to the message space. So Poly1305 (or GMAC) will have a finite number of possible messages they can authenticate, since they have finite key spaces (fixed key size). Therefore they don't have information-theoretic security. In practice you'll never use up the key space, 2^256 possible keys (and thus 2^128 birthday bound if choosing them randomly) will last until well after the sun goes red giant and vaporizes the surface of the Earth, even if you're making a new MAC every microsecond.